# Moving my RVM project gemset to another patchlevel

Tags: rvm

My project has an .rvmrc file with the following: `rvm 1.9.2-p180@project_name`. However, I just updated my ruby 1.9.2 to the latest patch level (1.9.2-p290). Is there any way to migrate the gems in the project_name gemset to 1.9.2-p290?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reference: http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/Upgrading-To-1-9-2-Using-Rvm_6.htm

Alternatively, your gemsets can be migrated (or moved) from one version of Ruby to another. Remember that migrate moves gemsets, not leaving a copy behind. But if you wish to do it this way, you can run the following command.

```
rvm migrate 1.9.2-p180@project_name 1.9.2-p290@project_name
```

Comment: The right command is: `rvm migrate source_ruby destination_ruby` and it moves *all* the gemsets

Answer (score 11):

You can [copy gemsets](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/copying/) with the following command:

```
rvm gemset copy 1.9.2-p180@project_name 1.9.2-p290@project_name
```

Comment: rvm gemset copy 2.0.0-p0 2.0.0-p195

Comment: Without specifying a gemset it appears to copy only the default gemset (*to* the default gemset).